# Session на разных под доменах

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, cookie, сессия

У меня в точности идентичный вопрос как тут [How can I share a session across multiple subdomains in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273732/how-can-i-share-a-session-across-multiple-subdomains-in-asp-net/2088853#2088853) только мне не помогла строка:

```
<httpCookies domain=".мой_домен"/>
```

подскажите может сталкивался кто то с похожим?

два домена *test1.site.ru* и *test2.site.ru* при переключении домена нужно что бы `Session` не сбрасывалась

Comment: Ну вы блин даёте... ответ 2008 года!.. за эти 10 лет столько воды утекло, столько версий IIS сменилось. Ниже, кстати есть ещё один совет от 2014 года, тоже однострочный -- попробуйте его для начала. И напишите в вопрос, какой у вас сервер и какая версия IIS, используете http или https и какой у вас механизм сессий - сами пилили или коробки используете, а то ну уж больно вопрос общий.

Comment: я использую 2008 R2, у меня http, механизм такой человек входит в ЛК и домена test1.site.ru и что бы заново не вводить логин и пароль и все такое я просто хочу хранить в Session["Author"], тобишь я просто беру и меняю test1. на test2. и уже нахожусь в другом ЛК

Comment: вы про вот эту одну строчку? machineKey decryptionKey = "12 ... D1" validationKey = "D7..8B"

Comment: я использую IIS7

Comment: machineKey decryptionKey = "12 ... D1" validationKey = "D7..8B" - это мне не помогло